# What is the difference between Optionals and Nullable type

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages, terminology

Swift has `Optionals`. C# has `Nullable` types.

As far as I can tell both serve same purpose, besides value of some type they store information whether variable has value or is undefined (uninitialized).

Question is are `Optionals` just `Nullable` types with different name or are there other conceptual differences?

In another words, talking about concept itself, or in context of languages that do not have `Optionals` or `Nullables`, does it matter whict term is used?

When implementing that functionality in language does it matter whether I name type `Optionals<T>` or `Nullable<T>`

Comment: From a language agnostic viewpoint, they are identical. That said, a language may differentiate the concepts (e.g. Whether or not pattern matching is enforced).

Comment: C# can have Options too (it's just a monadic pattern): https://github.com/louthy/language-ext

Comment: Using a null reference (or a NULL pointer, in languages with pointers) is a hack that some languages use to represent optional values, i.e. a container that may have one value or no value at all. This has the limitation that you can only consider optional a type that is based on references (or pointers). So, e.g., in Java you cannot make an integer optional without wrapping it in an object (e.g. Integer). Other languages provide optional types as generic types that can wrap any other type, e.g. Maybe in Haskell, Option in Scala, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a different connotation, even though they work very similarly.  *Everyone but Microsoft* (insert eye-roll here) uses `null` and `nullable` only in the context of references.  `Options` and `Maybes` are generally understood to refer to both references and values, especially in functional programming languages where referential transparency means there isn't much difference between a value and a reference.

> In another words, talking about concept itself, or in context of languages that do not have `Optionals` or `Nullables`, does it matter which term is used?

`Options` is the term that causes the least confusion among a broad audience.  Only C# programmers will think of a `Nullable` as potentially applying to a value type, and I think most of them are at least aware of what an `Option` is.

Comment: Everyone but Microsoft and the designers of SQL, I think you mean.

Answer (score 10):

In .NET, there are two categories of type: **references** and **values** (int, double, structs, enums etc). Amongst their differences is the fact that a reference can be `null`, whereas a value cannot. Thus if you have a value type and want to convey "optional" or "unknown" semantics, you can adorn it with `Nullable<>`. Note that `Nullable<>` is constrained by type to accept only value types (it has a `where T : struct` clause). `Nullable<>` also has special affordances from the compiler whereby a `null` value is protected from `NullReferenceExceptions`:

```
string x = null;
x.ToString(); // throws a NullReferenceException

int? y = null;
y.ToString(); // returns ""
```

In functional languages (such as Scala, F#, Haskell, Swift etc) it is common for `null` to **not exist**. This is because on the whole people regard the existence of `null` as a [bad idea](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare), and language designers have decided to address this problem by disallowing it.

This means that again we need some way to represent a **non-value** in these languages. Enter the `Option` type (nomenclature varies, it's called `Maybe` in Haskell). This does a similar job to `Nullable` in that it wraps a type to add the case where the value is "None" or "Unknown" etc.

The real difference is in the extra functions given to you by languages that implement `Option`. As an example, take `Option.map` (in pseudocode):

```
function Option<T2> Option.map(opt: Option<T1>, mapFunc: T1 -> T2) {
    if (opt is None) return None
    else return Option<T2>(mapFunc(opt.Value))
}
```

Chaining functions like `Option.map` is a powerful way to avoid the typical null check boilerplate you see everywhere in C#:

```
if (service == null)
    return null;
var x = service.GetValue();
if (x == null || x.Property == null)
    return null;
return x.Property.Value;
```

The Nullable equivalent in C# would be:

```
public static Nullable<T2> Map<T1, T2>(this Nullable<T1> nullable, Func<T1, T2> f)
    where T1 : struct
    where T2 : struct
{
    if (!nullable.HasValue) return (T2?)null;
    else return (T2?) f(nullable.Value);
}
```

However this has limited utility in C# because it will only work for value types.

The new version of C# offers the "null propagation" operator (`?.`) which is similar to the `Option.map` function except it is only applicable for methods and property accessors. The above sample would be rewritten

```
return service?.GetValue()?.Property?.Value;
```

Comment: C# is an impure functional language (just as F#). Also F# has nulls.

Comment: C# 6 has null value coercion, so at least some of your code is not up to date: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14 http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883

Comment: Also Options are easy to implement: https://github.com/louthy/language-ext

Comment: @Den: C# leans towards OOP while F# leans towards FP. Lack of currying and mutability by default means C# is not appropriate for serious functional programming. I mentioned null propagation at the end of the answer. Options are indeed simple to implement in C# but that strays from the question.

Comment: That sounds like a subjective opinion. Pure/impure is a quite objective definition. C# is impure and so is F#.

Comment: The compiler and the runtime indeed do have special affordances for `Nullable`, but I don't think your example shows that. Most of the time, `Nullable` behaves like another `struct`, and your example is consistent with that.

Comment: @Den I think there's some poor choice of words in your comments. An impure functional language is a functional language that allows side effects. C# may have some functional features and you can use them to great effect, but it's not a functional language. I guess you meant that neither language is 100% functional, but F# is very close to OCaml which is by most accounts a functional language. Whatever deviations it makes from the functional paradigm mostly exist so it can interoperate with foreign .NET code. Case in point, `null` is not a valid value for F# types.

Comment: @svick I was thinking more in terms for the fact that a `null` assignment permits method invocation; not applicable for a regular `struct` as `null` cannot be assigned

Comment: @Doval: "An impure functional language is a functional language that allows side effects.": I would rephrase this as "An impure functional language is a functional language in which expressions are not guaranteed to be referentially transparent." Using your definition, Haskell would be considered impure because it does allow side effects.